# surefire run tests compiled into jar

Tags: maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to achieve simple thing, compile all tests and its resources into a jar `test-all.jar` and be able to run tests from this jar later.

the one reason is that build takes about 7 minutes to compile everything and I would like to run tests in prallel on different machines, os etc.

so maven-jar-plugin has a `jar:test-jar`, copied the jar into `path/to/test/jar`, I ve configured surefire:3.0.0-M9 plugin. this surefire configuration works when run with all files in `target/test-classes`.

```
    mvn surefire:test -Dsurefire.includesFile=tests.suite
```

now I did `mvn clean` and would expect to run tests like

```
    mvn surefire:test -Dsurefire.includesFile=tests.suite -Dmaven.test.additionalClasspath=path/to/test/jar
```

but running this prints

> [exec] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo execution 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M9:test:default-cli' with basic configurator -->
> [exec] [DEBUG]   (s) additionalClasspathElements = [path/to/test/jar]
> [exec] [INFO] No tests to run.
> [exec] [DEBUG] Reading list from: tests.suite
> [exec] [DEBUG] List contents:
> [exec] [DEBUG] -- regressionsuites/TestAFeature
> [exec] [DEBUG] Resolved included and excluded patterns: regressionsuites/TestAFeature, !**/*$*

I ve found a post that advise to turnoff `useManifestOnlyJar` and `useSystemClassLoader` but no difference.
I ve tried adding `testClassesDirectory` to surefire configuration and at least surefire stops printing `[exec] [INFO] No tests to run.` but still no test is executed.

All in all I am looking for a right way to run test from a jar.

chatgpt told me to use

```
    <configuration>
        <jarFile>path/to/test-jar.jar</jarFile>
        <includes>
          <include>com/example/**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
```

but there is no such option listed in documentation for `test` goal and it is not working :D so much for AI help :-)

Comment: `chatgpt told me to use` so what? ChatGPT is simply wrong... a configuration like `jarFile` does simply not exists...https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html Also you can upgrade to most recent version 3.0.0 of surefire plugin... are those tests able to be run in parallel?  What junit testing frameowork do you use? Junit 4/JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)???

Comment: "chatgpt" has no model of right or wrong, correct or false. It simply combines words in sequence that is very likely. Don't use it for topics where you need precise information.